# How to group and plot values a bar chart matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, sample

I am trying to `group` all `values` into `months` and `plot` these as a `bar chart`. Below is what I have tried thus far:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = ({
    'Date' : ['1/7/18','1/7/18','1/8/18','1/8/18','1/9/18'],     
    'Value' : ['Foo','Bar','Foo','Bar','Foo'],           
    })

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
df1.resample('1M').count()['Value'].plot(kind = 'bar')
```

But this only produces `one bar` with a `count` of `5`. I'm hoping the intended output would be `3` separate `bars`. A `count` of `2` for `July`, `2` for `August`, and `1` for `September`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with converting to datetimes, need set format or `dayfirst=True`, because `DD/MM/YY`:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')
```

Or:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

And if need plot by month names use:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y').dt.month_name()
#alternative
#df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y').dt.strftime('%B')
df1.groupby('Date')['Value'].count().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image: g]

If need correct ordering of months:

```
months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August',
          'September','October','November','December']

df1['Date'] = pd.Categorical(df1['Date'], categories=months, ordered=True)
df1.groupby('Date')['Value'].count().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image: g1]

If want filter out `0` values:

```
df1.groupby('Date')['Value'].count().pipe(lambda x: x[x != 0]).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image: g2]

Thanks @asongtoruin for another idea:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y') 
#if necessary sorting datetimes
#df1 = df1.sort_values('Date')

df1['month_name'] = df1['Date'].dt.month_name()

df1.groupby('Date').agg({'Value': 'count', 'month_name': 'first'})
                   .plot(x='month_name', y='Value', kind='bar')
```

Comment: An alternative way to get the correct month order - `df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')` then `df1['month_name'] = df1['Date'].dt.month_name()` then `df1.groupby('Date').agg({'Value': 'count', 'month_name': 'first'}).plot(x='month_name', y='Value', kind='bar')`

Comment: @asongtoruin - Super idea, also added necessary sortied datetimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine, but you've mixed up the day/month format

All you need to do is change

```
'Date' : ['1/7/18','1/7/18','1/8/18','1/8/18','1/9/18'],
```

To

```
'Date' : ['7/1/18','7/1/18','8/1/18','8/1/18','9/1/18'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a pivot table to group by the dates.

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, values='Value', index='Date', aggfunc='count').plot(kind='bar')
```